# Unix\AIX Script Error: "0403-015 Cannot access a required executable file. It is in use" & "Cannot Open or Remove a file Containing a Running Program"

Tags: linux, unix, interpreter, aix

Most of the times you create/place a script on/from Windows or WinSCP to a Unix machine without using vi command you will most likely encounter the errors below.

From what I saw it always happens because of special characters that look like simple space but are preformatted from Outlook or other tools.

**Errors Encountered:**

ksh:

> 0403-015 Cannot access a required executable file. It is in use.

bash:

> /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: Cannot Open or Remove a file Containing a Running Program

Comment: That's right, CR characters (0x0D) aren't welcome in Unix. Try this: `sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//'  file.windows >file.unix` (note: \s doesn't work in AIX!sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your script on a Linux machine and run the following command:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' Your_Script.sh
```

Command Explained:

sed

> stream editor for filtering and transforming text

-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

-e script, --expression=script

> add the script to the commands to be executed

Answer (score 0):

Upload the script in WinSCP using the "Text" mode.
See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode

You better enable the "Automatic" mode, instead of explicit "Text", so that you won't laster inadvertently upload binary files like images using the text mode.